# Update multiple divs with dropbox value, 1 dropbox working, 1 is not

Tags: jquery, html

Our site is responsive so the tablet and desktop view is the same page but just a different layout due to show / hide div elements.

Its hard to explain so ive copied the code into jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/4wsqpjrn/

**Im trying to get both dropdown boxes to update the divs, what im i missing?**

ive duplicated the fields so its how it would be rendered in the page, when viewed from a tablet, the 2 desktop divs are hidden, from desktop, the 2 tablet divs are hidden.

The tablet divs are rendered first in the page following by the desktop.

The jquery is at the bottom on the page

```
jQuery('#product-options').change(function (event) {
jQuery('.product-price').html(jQuery('#product-options option:selected').attr('data-price'));
jQuery('.aep').html(jQuery('#product-options option:selected').attr('data-aep'));
}).change(); //to iniitize the value on load
```

the tablet side works fine, it changes the value in both the tablet and desktop divs but the desktop dropdown box doesn't work at all?

the html code is pulled from an include file twice, once for tablet, once for desktop.

```
<div style="padding-bottom:3px">
<div class="inline"><font class="was_style">
<b>Was &pound;</b></font></div><div class="inline"><div class="aep aep_style">479</div></div>


<div style="padding-bottom:5px">
<div class="inline"><font class="product_price now_style">&pound;</font>    
</div><font class="product_price now_style"><div class="product-price inline" itemprop="price">349</div></font></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your selects are sharing the same ID.
Rename them to: product-options-desktop and product-options-tablet and use the code below.

```
jQuery('#product-options-desktop').change(function (event) {
jQuery('.product-price').html(jQuery('#product-options-desktop option:selected').attr('data-price'));
jQuery('.aep').html(jQuery('#product-options-desktop option:selected').attr('data-aep'));
    }).change(); //to iniitize the value on load

jQuery('#product-options-tablet').change(function (event) {
jQuery('.product-price').html(jQuery('#product-options-tablet option:selected').attr('data-price'));
jQuery('.aep').html(jQuery('#product-options-tablet option:selected').attr('data-aep'));
    }).change();
```

This should fix this issue for now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i have updated the fiddle with your suggestion and added the extra lines to jquery but it still doesnt work? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4wsqpjrn/1/)

Comment: I updated my answer and it works in your fiddle. Hopefully thats it.